# Using XPath select all elements that contains a child element with an attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to use xpath to select all the node elements that contain a child element that has any value for the restriction attribute other than an empty string.

Here is my xml:

```
<nodes code="C">
   <node code="A">
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="value" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
   </node>
   <node code="B">
      <child restriction="value" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
   </node>
   <node code="C">
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
      <child restriction="" />
   </node>
</nodes>
```

My working xpath is:

```
nodes/node[(child/@restriction and string-length(child/@restriction) > 0)]
```

This only returns node B, presumably because B is the only element where the restriction value appears first.  My aim is to return both B and A but not C.

Can someone point out where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
nodes/node[child/@restriction[string()]]
```

This tests each `restriction` attribute for the existence of a string content.

In your version, you try to convert the node-set of `child/@restriction` into a string to be used as the argument for `string-length()`. In XSLT 1.0, this would return the value of the first node in the set; in XSLT 2.0, this would produce an error.

Comment: Also very helpful explanation about why I was only getting the first result back.